# How to use JQuery validation plugin with conditions?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using JQuery validation plugin to validate my form.

I have a radio button on the top.  if you  pick "yes",  some input fields will show up. if you pick "no", different input fields will be used.

How do I change my validation codes, so It will validate those fields based on the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple if you're just worried about `required` fields. You can supply a dependency for the `required` rule:

```
$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        Yes1: {
            required: "#yes:checked"
        },
        Yes2: {
            required: "#yes:checked"
        },
        No1: {
            required: "#no:checked"
        },
        No2: {
            required: "#no:checked"
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/7SYcE/

Now, this gets more complicated if you're using other rules. I will expand my answer if this isn't powerful enough for you.